# Sie kann ihre Herkunft nicht verbergen, allerdings liegt ihr auch nichts ferner

Tags: meaning-in-context

There are 3 adverbs in this sentence. But what does "ferner" in particular mean?

Comment: This is an idiom. "Ihr liegt nichts ferner" = "she wouldn't dream of doing that".

Comment: The proper sentence would end such as *...nichts ferner, als das zu tun*"

Comment: https://dict.leo.org/german-english/ferner+liegen

Answer (score 5):

*fern* (German) = *far (away)* (English)
*ferner* ist the comparative (*farther/further*)

> Etwas liegt fern = Something is far away (literally: Something lies far away) -- it is beyond me/her/you/etc.
>   Etwas liegt jemandem fern = Something is far away from somebody's point of view (in somebody's mind)
>   Etwas liegt jemandem ferner = Something is further away from somebody's point of view
>
> Nichts liegt ihr ferner = Nothing is further away from her point of view

You can interpret "from her point of view" also as "in her mind".